# Compile symbolic c++ application with cmake

Tags: c++, g++, cmake

I'm using `ubuntu 12.03` and trying to use `Symbolicc++` library, it is specified in it's README file that the program using this library should be compiled with command `g++ -o program program.cpp -lsymbolicc++`. I am wondering how can I enter the `-lsymbolicc++` pastfix in the `cmakelists.txt` file and work on kdevelop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have program added as an executable to cmakelists.txt a'la;

```
add_executable(program program.cpp)
```

then you can just add

```
target_link_libraries(program symbolicc++)
```

to add that library when linking.